# How can I set the TARGET.dir property in Scons?

Tags: python, scons

In a SConstruct script, there is an area where the following is called:

```
env.Command(
    [[kl2edkBin, "-o", "${TARGET.dir}"] + klSources]
)
```

I want to set the value of that TARGET.dir.  But I have no idea where it is coming from.  How can I change the inputs to that kl2edk command (without modifying that SConstruct file)?

this may be a very stupid question.  I'm trying to get something working while learning the least possible scons, and to top it off I'm not a regular python user.  I've spent a bit of time googling, but nothing comes up, which suggests to me I'm misunderstanding something at a very fundamental level.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to "get working"? When I google for kl2edk I get hits that refer to the Fabric engine/project. Why can't you use their build system out of the box, but have to change output dirs? If you get build errors it would help if you could attach them verbatim to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what information is relevant and what is not.I am trying to keep my source folder clean.  The command above creates generated files at the argument specified by ${TARGET.dir}.  I want to change the input to the command so that my generated files go elsewhere, and the line suggests that TARGET.dir is a variable *somehow* that I should be able to modify.  The build itself works fine, but I hate a messy source folder

Comment: I can't/don't want to change the line itself, as it is in the SConscript that comes with the Fabric Engine package.  I wont change their script if I can help it (saves time on version updates etc).

Comment: So the build actually works, but you simply don't like the fact that some generated files are created in the source folder? Keep in mind that other build steps might depend on these generated files, and their location relative to the project's root folder...so you'll run into errors when patching this output dir.

Comment: If I hard-code the argument (ie, I just replace the ${OUTPUT.dir} with "c:/SomeFolder/" then things seem to carry on and the result is (mostly) as desired - all source files in one directory, generated files in another, and the build ready to run in a 3rd.  But yes - I understand I'm running the risk of having to actually understand scons :)

Comment: Regarding the "risk of having to actually understand scons": Things could be worse. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "TARGET" in the Command refers to the path of the first given target, and "TARGET.dir" returns its folder (=dirname) dynamically. So you can't easily change the output dir without touching the SConstruct...

Comment: Thanks.  I'll copy the SConscript local then, and start reading scons 'HelloWorld'...